# My jframe doesn't shows

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I'm beginner woth java programming

I tried to make my jframe shows but it didn't

```
jframe.setVisible(true);
```

it doesn't works

Comment: provide full program to get clear idea

Comment: We'll need more than this. Consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: That's not enough to go by.  We need to see a runnable example of what you are doing before we can assist you

Comment: Erm, you didn't provide enough information. `frame.setVisible(true);` should effectively display your frame but how did you create/initialize it, and where?

Comment: `jframe` isn't declared in your code. That's probably it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you didn't declare correctly your JFrame. Here is an example creating a simple frame :

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // Creating a frame
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Example");
    // Setting the position and the size of the frame
    frame.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
    // This will terminate the program when closing the frame
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    // Then you can display your frame
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: thanks i didnt put the 1st line